# Cannot conver varchar to numeric datatype

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have some datatype conversion problems.

List B is the raw data in `varchar`
To get rid of `'-'`, I used `REPLACE(PPRICE,'-','')`
List A is in `varchar` as well.

However, when I want to convert the datatype to numeric (18,4) by

```
CONVERT(numeric(18, 4),REPLACE(PPRICE,'-',''))
```

SQL Server won't let me do it.

Does anyone know why?

By the way, some values in the lists are empty.

```
 A   B
1800    1800
75.44   75.44
75.44   75.44
20       000020-
25       000025-
250 250
```

Comment: "SQL Server won't let me do it." What's the error you got? I have no problem to convert the data you listed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like convert fails due to empty values in the list. Try this by cater for empty data using a case statement.

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 4),REPLACE( CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(PPRICE)) <> '' THEN 0 ELSE A END,'-',''))
```